# firebase function to trigger notification

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to create a firebase function which will trigger a notification when there is new entry pushed in the table.
I have the separate table which contains all the device tokens. Cannot figure out how exactly to fetch each device token from the table.
Here is some code snippet of firebase function which I have written so far but had no luck with it.

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotificationToAllMembers = functions.database.ref('/chatRoom/{messageNode}').onWrite(event => {
  const messageInfo = event.params.messageNode;

  // Get the list of device notification tokens.
  const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/deviceTokens`).once('value');

  // Get newly added Message detail
  const getMovieMessageDetail = admin.database().ref(`/chatRoom/${messageInfo}`).once('value');

  return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise, getMovieMessageDetail]).then(results => {
    const deviceTokensList = results[0];
    const MessageDetail = results[1];
console.log('device tokens : ',deviceTokensList);
console.log('Fetched message detail', MessageDetail);
    // Check if there are any device tokens.
    if (!deviceTokensList.hasChildren()) {
      return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
    }
    console.log('There are', deviceTokensList.numChildren(), 'tokens to send notifications to.');

    // Notification details.
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: 'New Movie discussion',
        body: `${MessageDetail.messageText}`,
      }
    };

    // Listing all tokens.
    const tokens = Object.keys(deviceTokensList.val());

    // Send notifications to all tokens.
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
      // For each message check if there was an error.
      const tokensToRemove = [];
      response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
          console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
          // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
          if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
              error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
            tokensToRemove.push(deviceTokensList.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
          }
        }
      });
      return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
    });
  });
});
```

Here are snapshots of firebase real-time database which I am referring to,
I.E. whenever there is a push in 'chatRoom' table, I want to send a notification to each device token present in 'deviceTokens' table.
[image: firebase real-time database snapshot]

thanks a ton in advance !!

Comment: What is the problem with the code you currently have implemented?

Comment: The same problem by me. It gets the -KvZ-vH8.... instead of a value from child deviceToken. It should get fmGRCjoUwWG.... - these values, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Either change the structure, or stay with it, but when you send the data to the database, try using the set().

```
db.ref("deviceTokens").set({[token] : token}).ref.child("tokenID").set(token);
```

But, having more users does not work well with it.

With this one, it would read the token and the user would get the push notification.

But, the set() is limited, so even with push() - which generates unique key,

You can try with:

```
var firebaseRef = db.ref("deviceTokens").child(token).child("tokenId");
  firebaseRef.set({
     text : 'some other text field'
});
```

But, you will have to have the unique token to store into the database, I think?